# Clone SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a 2 databases on 2 servers, Server A db1 and Server B db2.

Db 1 is a clone of db 2 from 2 weeks ago, and was never updated since then.

There is a short way to make db1 exactly like db2?

Comment: Backup `db2` and restore it over `db1` seems like the simplest and quickest version

Comment: You may get better results asking in [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). That's designed specifically for Database Administration issues.

Answer (score 1):

a backup from one, and restore to the other is probably the easiest - but you could also used redgates sql compare/data compare tools to find differences for you and move the changes from the source to the target database.

I believe there is a 14+/- day trial for both, so you could try them out. I own all of the redgate tools and find them invaluable for these (and other) problems:

https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Comment: I agree backup/restore is the easiest way to make sure db1 is exactly the same as db2. One could also use [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) to compare database schema and data.